# Geographical center of countries

Tags: geospatial

Can anyone help me find a list of the geographical centers of all the countries of the world? Preferably without calculating them from other data.

Answer (score 3):

I found several sources of "country centroids."

- Country Centroids, from worldmap.harvard.edu, available to download in many formats (Zipped Shapefile, GML 2.0, GML 3.1.1, CSV, Excel, GeoJSON, GeoTIFF, JPEG, PDF, PNG, KML, View in Google Earth). Also available as a web map service. This dataset comes with *a lot* (80-ish) of attributes.

  - https://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:country_centroids_az8
- From Google, there's a simple table of lat/long coordinates for countries. Just 4 columns: 2-letter country code, latitude, longitude, and country name. (There's no download link. Just highlight the table and copy-paste it into a spreadsheet.)

  - https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv
- On periscopedata.com, Country Centroids: Geographic centers of countries in lat-long coordinates. Posted by a site user named Sean Cook, self-described Product Analyst @ Facebook

  - https://community.periscopedata.com/t/63fy7m/country-centroids

And of course there are many sources of country boundaries, which you can convert to centroids and export as lat/long coordinates in any GIS software.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, there is usually no universally agreed upon geographical centre for a country; it depends on how you measure certain parameters.

Second, this probably isn't the right place to be asking this question.

Having said that, have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71921/list-of-central-coordinates-for-all-countries) and [here](http://webs.schule.at/website/Europa/Europa_centre_en.htm#Ireland).

Comment: _why_ would this not be the right place?  it violates terms? there are places with more people who know about this specific type of data? etc?